# Creating PHP relay using sockets between multiple clients and servers

Tags: php, sockets

I've got a Python server which multiple clients connect to using sockets.  At the moment one server isn't able to cope with the load so I'm looking at ways to split the clients up according to some criteria such as their username.

The intention is to put clients with usernames starting with A-G on server 1, H-P on server 2 and P-Z on server 3.

What I'm trying to do is to write a process that will listen for connections on port 45000 and will then forward those on to the appropriate server on 45001, 45002 and 45003.

At the moment, when a client connects to the original server they connect via a TCP port e.g. 45000.  The server checks that they are authorised and responds on a random port with a handshake e.g. 59117, 60647 or 61573.

The response port is not specified when the client first connects so my question is, when is the value determined and how does the client know to listen on that port for the reply ?

So far I've written a PHP process which takes the data from the clients and forwards it to the appropriate server but I can't work out which port to listen on for the response back from the server.  Is there some way that PHP sockets can negotiate the response port so that it can be stored in a variable in my script ?

Here's my basic connection code in PHP.  I have no knowledge of Python so this is going to have to be done in PHP:

```
// Define remote Server
$socket=socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP);

// Open socket on remote server to send $buf data to
socket_connect($socket, 'X.X.X.X', 40149);

echo ("Forwarding data ($buf) to $socket ....\r\n");
$bytesWritten=socket_write($socket, $buf, strlen($buf));
echo ("Wrote: $bytesWritten bytes\r\n");

// Now listen for response but this will be on another socket
// How do we know what this is ?
if (false === ($response = socket_read($socket, 16384))) {
    echo ("Response: $response\r\n");
}
```

This is way out of my comfort zone so I may have this completely wrong but an afternoon spent Googling has turned up any answers yet.

Comment: I really question a load balancing strategy which is based on end user's name.

Comment: Thanks for the insight Mike.  I chose username as an example - I may use another approach but whatever I use it doesn't really matter to the question itself ...

Comment: Well. It might matter to the question at hand. My guess is that you don't want to implement any load balancing within PHP itself, but rather push this functionality as early in the request stack as possible, using a load balancing application that is truly meant for that purpose.  Without that, you are just moving your single point of failure a bit out of your Python application and into your PHP application.  I am guessing that if you are already out of your comfort zone, that you coming up with your own load balancing implementation is not a good strategy.

Comment: I can't use a regular load balancing system as I need to assign clients to servers based on some parameter passed in during the login process.  As far as I am aware, no off the shelf load balancing system allows me to do that hence why I am rolling my own ...

Comment: That is why I am questioning the approach of why you need to load balance based on some user-provided data.  That doesn't seem to make sense and would potentially make your infrastructure susceptible to being browned out by end users providing bad/unexpected data.

Comment: It isn't clear to me what you're trying to do. Why do you need to "respond on a random port"? You already have a unique connection from client to server. Are you attempting to have the load-balancer *proxy* to the real backends? Or do you mean to *redirect* the clients to the real backends? Or do you mean to tell one of the backends where the client is and to have the backend *connect back* to the client? (The last sounds closest to what you're describing but seems like a complicated solution.)